# Clojure macro for searching in lists of maps using an SQL-like syntax

Tags: clojure, macros

## Example input

```
=> (def persons '({:id 1 :name "olle"} {:id 2 :name "anna"} {:id 3 :name
"isak"} {:id 4 :name "beatrice"}))

=> (select [:id :name] from persons where [:id > 2] orderby :name)
```

## Example Output

```
({:id 4 :name "beatrice"} {:id 3 :name "isak"})
```

The query format should be:

```
(select [columns]
from #{table}
where [:column op value]
orderby :column)
```

where 'op' is equal to one of '=' '<' '>' or '<>'

## Attempted solution

```
(defmacro select
    [vara _ coll _ wherearg _ orderarg]
    '(map [~vara]
        (filter [~wherearg]
            (sort-by ~orderarg) ~coll)
        )
    )
```

What more does my solution need?
I don't understand what the errors mean so I don't even know what I should look for to find a solution.

```
IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:542)
```

Comment: You are doing far too many things at once. Use the REPL to construct your program piece by piece and see where you go wrong. I don’t think we can help you with the info you posted here.

Comment: @glts
When I try to shorten the macro to `(defmacro select
    [var ]
        `(map (fn [~var])` (when I shorten the macro to the first 3 lines) I get the error `CompilerException java.lang.Exception: Unsupported binding form: :id, compiling:(/private/var/folders/6f/q7lhngtn45q_xpzd_24gjp2h0000gn/T/form-init388258705784899144.clj:1:1)` and am not really sure what to do about it. Do you know what this is about at least?

Comment: Try using the `macroexpand` and `clojure.walk/macroexpand-all` utilities on one of your `select` expressions to see what it expands to.

Comment: @glts `(clojure.pprint/pprint (macroexpand `(select [:id :name])))
(clojure.core/map (clojure.core/fn [[:id :name]]))
nil`

While `(macroexpand (select [:id :name]))` produces the same error

Comment: `macroexpand` expects a form as the argument: `(macroexpand '(select ,,,))`.

Comment: Sorry, my commend was supposed to contain that but my comment interpreted it not as a literal '

Comment: I agree with @glts. You really need to learn the language gauge before you stand making a ton of macros. You probably shouldn't even be trying to make macros yet, as all they do is complicated things and build on existing knowledge about functions. Without a good base knowledge of the language, you're going to be fighting a constant uphill battle and not get a lot done.

Comment: @Carcigenicate This macro and another one are probably the only things I'll ever code in closure.

Comment: @Jacob Well, you can't expect to start sprinting before you can walk and have that and well. I encourage you to actually sit down with the language and give it a fair chance. I had been writing Clojure for a couple months before I was able to start writing my own useful macros. Trying to expedite the process won't help you learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it the Clojure way, using regular function composition and macros for syntax sugar:

Your particular example can be solved as follows:

```
(->> persons
     (filter #(>= (:id %) 2))
     (sort-by :name)
     (map #(select-keys % [:id :name]))
```

But lets try to create a more generic sort of solution.

```
(defn select
  "Takes a set of keys as input, returns a transducer
   which will select only the given keys for each item"
  [& keys]
  (map #(select-keys % keys)))

(defn filter-by [field predicate]
  (filter #(-> % field predicate)))

(defn filter-by-name [user-name]
  "Filters by users with the given name"
  (filter-by :name #(= % user-name)))

(defn filter-by-age [user-age]
  "Filters by users with the given age"
  (filter-by :age #(= % user-age))

(defn filter-by-age-over [user-age]
  "Filters by users with the age strictly above user-age"
  (filter-by :age #(> % user-age))

(defn filter-by-age-below [user-age]
  "Filters by users with the age strictly below user-age"
  (filter-by :age #(< % user-age))

(defn filter-by-id-over [id-val]
  (filter-by :id #(> % id-val))

(defn filter-by-gender [gender]
  (filter-by :gender #(= % gender))
```

We can now use these functions as follows

```
(def xf-charly-age-5 
  (comp (filter-by-name "Charly") 
        (filter-by-age 5) 
        (select :name :id)))

(defn xf-adults
  (comp (filter-by-age-over 18) 
        (select :name :id)))

(defn xf-male-adults
  (comp (filter-by-age-over 18) 
        (filter-by-gender :male)
        (select :name :id)))

(defn search-users [xf users]
  (->> (into [] xf users)
       (sort-by
```

Which you can now use as follows:

```
(search-users xf-male-adults all-users)
(search-users xf-adults all-users)
(search-users xf-charly-age-5 all-users
```

**Note on Sorting:**

Unfortunately Clojure doesn't come with a sort transducer. You can however get one from [https://github.com/cgrand/xforms](http://cgrand's%20popular%20xforms) project or implement the sorting by yourself using the `sort-by` function.

Answer (score 1):

I would break up the problem, and stick to regular Clojure syntax instead of trying to re-invent SQL.  Something like this:

```
(def persons '( {:id 1 :name "olle"}
                {:id 2 :name "anna"}
                {:id 3 :name "isak"}
                {:id 4 :name "beatrice"} ))

(defn id-over-2?
  [person]
  (< 2 (:id person)))

(def persons-2 (filter id-over-2? persons) )

(def persons-3 (sort-by :name persons-2))
```

with results

```
persons-2 => ({:id 3, :name "isak"} {:id 4, :name "beatrice"})

persons-3 => ({:id 4, :name "beatrice"} {:id 3, :name "isak"})
```